# Impala: values are in wrong columns in result query

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

In my result query the values are in wrong columns.

My SQL Query is like:

```
create table some_database.table name as
select 
     extract(year from t.operation_date) operation_year,
     extract(month from t.operation_date) operation_month,
     extract(day from t.operation_date) operation_day,
     d.status_name,
     sum(t.operation_amount) operation_amt,
     current_timestamp() calculation_moment
from operations t
left join status_dict d on
     d.status_id = t.status_id
group by
     extract(year from t.operation_date) operation_year,
     extract(month from t.operation_date) operation_month,
     extract(day from t.operation_date) operation_day,
     d.status_name
```

(In fact, it's more complicated, but the main idea is that I'm aggregating source table and making some joins.)

The result I get is like:

| # | operation_year | operation_month | operation_day | status_name | operation_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | 1 | 1 | success | 100 |
| 2 | 2021 | 1 | 1 | success | 150 |
| 3 | 2021 | 1 | 2 | success | 120 |
| 4 | null | 2021-01-01 21:53:00 | success | 120 | null |

The problem is in row 4.

- The field *t.operation_date* is not nullable, but in result query in column operation_year we get null
- In operation_month we get untruncated timestamp
- In operation_day we get string value from *d.status_name*
- In status_name we get numeric aggregate from *t.operation_amount*
- In operation_amt we get null

It looks very similar to a wrong parsing of a csv file when values jump to other columns, but obviously it can't be the case here. I can't figure out how on earth is it possible. I'm new to Hadoop and apparently I'm not aware of some important concept which causes the problem.

Comment: it looks like a source data issue. can you pls post exact source data here? Also, i think your sql has wrong group by - group by cant have column alias (but i assume its copy paste error)

Comment: @KoushikRoy that was the main issue - to localize the row that causes the problem. But we did it and the issue was caused by new line inside a value in a value. So  my worst fears were realized - it behaves like parsing a malformatted csv file. Maybe if I come across with this issue again, I'll post the data here=)